# Looking for an iterative method to fit a beta-exponential distribution to a dataset

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I have a messy beta-exponential distribution that has 3 variables that I have to fit to from a dataset with 50 observations.

The problem is that I only know how to use Newton-Raphson for 1 variable.

My question is what optimization method can I use to fit this distribution, in conjunction with the method of maximum likelihood.

If it's possible, please link to a page with a how-to for the optimization method and example code.

Comment: You read about the generalisation of the Newton-Raphson method to systems of equations on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Nonlinear_systems_of_equations) therefore if you are already happy coding up the univariate NR method then it should be straight forward to modify it to accept vectors of parameters and replacing the divison by $f'(x)$ with multiplication by the inverse of the Jacobian.

Comment: Use the Solve facility in Excel. It is an add-on which you may have to install, but it can usually handle this sort of problem OK.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help. One of the reasons I was having problems was because deriving the MLE for the beta-exponential distribution was really hard. I thought I could derive it and solve it with matrices but my method was really hard to  implement.

Instead, I used a pre-programmed function in SAS called NLP in order to find my parameters and fit the distribution. This is the code I wrote.

Note1: The data set was in a CSV file.
Note2: The question

Let (,)=∫^(−1)*(1−)^(−1).
A random variable is said to follow a beta-exponential distribution with parameters >0, >0, >0 if it has density
 ()=  (exp((−)/)(1−exp(−/))^(−1))/(,)  >0, 
            0                                                                ≤0.
I had to find parameters alpha, beta, lambda by fitting a given dataset to this distribution.

PROC iml;
use WORK.BETA;
read all into x;
close;
start F_BETTS(param) global(x); /*Calculates MLE*/

```
y= param[1];/* y is lambda*/
a= param[2];/* a is alpha*/
b= param[3];/* b is beta*/
n= nrow(x);
F_BETTS = j(n,1,.);

    do i=1 to n;
    F_BETTS[i]=(exp(-b*x[i]/y)*(1-exp(-x[i]/y))**(a-1))/(y*beta(a,b)); /*Beta-exponential distribution*/
    end;

f = sum(log(F_BETTS));
return(f);
```

finish;

con ={0.01 0.01 0.01,
 . . .};   /*Sets min constraints to barely over 1 and max constraints to infinity*/

Initial={4 2 10}; /* Initial parameter */
opt={1 4}; /* finds maximum with lots of output*/

call nlpnra(rc, xres, "F_BETTS", Initial, opt, con);

run;
quit;